# Performance of JOIN then UNION vs. UNION then JOIN

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, query-performance

I have a SQL query along the following lines:

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM table1
        INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.id = table3.id
    WHERE table1.condition = 'something'
),

b AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM table2
        INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.id = table3.id
    WHERE table2.condition = 'something else'
),

combined AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM a
    UNION
    SELECT *
    FROM b
)

SELECT *
FROM combined
```

I rewrote this as:

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM table1
    WHERE table1.condition = 'something'
),

b AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM table2
    WHERE table2.condition = 'something else'
),

combined AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM a
        UNION
        SELECT *
        FROM b
    ) union
    INNER JOIN table3 ON union.id = table3.id
)

SELECT *
FROM combined
```

I expected that this might be more performant, since it's only doing the `JOIN` once, or at the very least that it would have no effect on execution time. I was surprised to find that the query now takes almost twice as long to run.

This is no problem since it worked perfectly well before, I only really rewrote it out of my own personal style preference anyway so I'll stick with the original. But I'm no expert when it comes to databases/SQL, so I was interested to know if anyone can share any insights as to why this second approach is so much less performant?

If it makes a difference, it's a Redshift database, `table1` and `table2` are both around ~250 million rows, `table3` is ~1 million rows, and `combined` has less than 1000 rows.

Comment: You need to generate execution plans for the two queries and see where they differ. In *general*, if two queries logically produce the same result, the optimizer *should* generate the same plan. Because in SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*.

Comment: Of course the first onse is more efficient: the two joins can use indexes and statistics. After the CTEs all table structure is lost, and everything is reduced to heap table scans and hash joins.

Comment: @wildplasser Unless that is true specifically for amazon redshift, which I have no experience of, I don't think that is true. A CTE is nothing more than a expression, and all indexes and statistics persist to the final use of said expression.

Comment: @GarethD In postgres SQL a CTE is an optimisation barrier, at least before PG-12 (IIRC). Redshift is some older (possibly crippled) PG version.

Comment: @wildplasser Interesting. I stand corrected.

Comment: To the OP: is there any reason for **not** using `UNION ALL` ?

Comment: The original author may have had their reasons (I 'inherited' the original query, didn't write it myself), but no I don't see any reason for not using ```UNION ALL```, there shouldn't be any duplicates. I guess it hadn't really twigged that it was a ```UNION``` not a ```UNION ALL``` (like I said, I'm no SQL expert!), but of course it makes perfect sense that sorting and removing dupes is much more costly in the second case. Thanks all for educating me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL optimizer has more information on "bare" tables than on "computed" tables.  So, it is easier to optimize the two CTEs.

In a database that uses indexes, this might affect index usage.  In Redshift, this might incur additional data movement.

In this particular case, though, I suspect the issue might have to do with filtering via the `JOIN` operation.  The `UNION` is incurring overhead to remove duplicates.  By filtering *before* the `UNION`, duplicate removal is faster than filtering afterwards.

In addition, the `UNION` may affect where the data is located, so the second version might require additional data movement.